# how to use kinect data without rviz or rgdslam

Tags: ros, kinect, gui, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm a totally newbie in ros and qt, and I would like to make a GUI in QT with a window showing a pointcloud image and another window showing a normal image, and after I might try to add some control but my issue is that I really don't know which way I have to take.
I've starting to do almost all the tutorials I found interesting for my purpose, and now I'm starting to read rviz code to understand how I can extract images from the kinect.

I've been looking for something like my idea everywhere but I didn't find anything.
Should I continue to read rviz code? I'm kind of scared when I see all this lines...

Thanks for the help.

Cheers

(I'm using ros electric with ubuntu).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35093/how-to-use-kinect-data-without-rviz-or-rgdslam/) by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably upgrade to fuerte, as rviz has been ported to QT and modularized with this new distro. The [Librviz Tutorial](http://ros.org/doc/api/librviz_tutorial/html/) looks like it is very relevant (and in parts similar) to what you describe.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-07-16**:
Is there other tutorials that this one? because I didn't succeed to add a point cloud in my grid or when I add an Image Display, this one creates a new window...